# iphone 6 simulator size

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode6

I have xCode 6 and I just want to see my app running on iphone 6 for testing. xCode 6 consist of resizable iphone simulator and I would like to know what size to use. Rumours say iPhone will be in 4.7" and 5.5".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with: 1704 x 960

See references at the following links:

http://www.jailbreakmodo.com/iphone-6-to-have-higher-screen-resolution.html

http://www.fpblog.net/blog/2014/6/22/how-apple-could-use-3x-scaling-for-the-iphone-6-and-ipad-pro

In the simulator you should set 480 X 852

Answer (score 0):

As of now I'm an eager learner and long loved loyal apple fan. I'm not an expert on iOS but any thing could happen between the September 9 launch and now. Most likely they will have the small screen size first based on rumors, then launch the new phone later that month or based on new surfacing rumors they may only announce one phone. The odds are pretty good there will be a 4.7 and 5.5 inch display. China leaks images of both sizes but We have no idea what the dimensions are yet so all I can say is it's up to fate what apple chooses.
Best of luck,
- Dev

Answer (score 0):

iPhone 6/6 Plus being unveiled, the official sizes are:

- iPhone 6 1334x750
- iPhone 6 Plus 1920x1080

http://www.apple.com/iphone-6/specs/